# Can't set string const System.Environment.CurrentDirectory;

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have trouble initializing a const:

> The expression being assigned to 'path' must be constant (CS0133)

My code:

```
using System;

namespace study
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            // Here I get this error
            const string path = System.Environment.CurrentDirectory; 

            // This here is ok
            string path = System.Environment.CurrentDirectory;
        }
    }
}
```

With `.ToString()` method - also have trouble.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't do this because constants are compile-time values. They cease to exist as a named entity when the program is compiled because the values are directly substituted (source: [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/constants)):

> In this example, the constant months is always 12, and it cannot be changed even by the class itself. **In fact, when the compiler encounters a constant identifier in C# source code (for example, months), it substitutes the literal value directly into the intermediate language (IL) code that it produces.** Because there is no variable address associated with a constant at run time, const fields cannot be passed by reference and cannot appear as an l-value in an expression.

Even if this did work, you would only have the value of the current directory on the machine that compiled the code, not the machine that's running the code. That doesn't make much sense.

While you can't use this in methods, if you need global "constant"-esque values such as this, you can define them like so:

```
public static readonly string Path = System.Environment.CurrentDirectory;
```

Though why you wouldn't just use `System.Environment.CurrentDirectory`, I don't know.

Comment: Because path is the const that uisng in some parts of code.

Comment: I'm not sure what that means?

Comment: I need to use System.Environment.CurrentDirectory like const or 'static field'; Just because I need to declare a path and never change him. Or this is bad practic?

Comment: @GregorySysoev Use a static field then. It's impossible with `const` for the reasons outlined in my answer. Imagine if this was valid code: `const path = Environment.CurrentDirectory;`. On your build machine, you compile your application to `c:\build\myApplication.exe`. Doing so replaces any instance of `path` in your code with "c:\build\". You then move the compiled executable to a different folder, or a different machine. What relevance does "c:\build\" have on a different machine? That's why you can't do this kind of thing.

Answer (score 2):

The issue is that you're trying to assign a dynamic value to a constant variable.

The constant must be a literal string (or existing constant) and should not be reassigned.

Comment: Can he just use `D\Folder_Name`

Comment: How to assign a constant to this value?

Comment: @Gregory can you clarify what you're asking? `const int a = 5;` would work, `const string a = "test";` would work